# How to keep kivy service running in background in Android (service still run when switch to other App or lock the screen)?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an android APP with kivy,my requirement is quit simple:

When open the android APP,it will start counting from 0, and a prompt will pop up in the status bar every 5 seconds. The prompt content is the current count value. If the APP is switched to the background or the screen is locked, a prompt will still pop up in the status bar every 5 seconds.

here is the code I modified from Internet:

```
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from plyer import notification
from plyer.utils import platform
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
kivy.require('1.8.0')

a = 0
from kivy.utils import platform
if platform == 'android':
    #pass
    from jnius import autoclass
    package_name = 'net.saband.myapp'
    service_name = 'ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY'
    service = autoclass('{}.Service{}'.format(package_name, service_name))
    mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
    service.start(mActivity, '')

class NotificationDemo(BoxLayout):
    kwargs = DictProperty()
    def update(self,dt):
        global a
        a = a + 1
        mode = 'fancy'
        message = str(a)
        title = self.ids.notification_title.text
        self.ids.notification_text.text = message
        ticker = self.ids.ticker_text.text
        self.kwargs = {'title': title, 'message': message, 'ticker': ticker}
        if mode == 'fancy':
            self.kwargs['app_name'] = "Plyer Notification Example"
            if platform == "win":
                self.kwargs['app_icon'] = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)),
                                          'plyer-icon.ico')
                self.kwargs['timeout'] = 4
            else:
                self.kwargs['app_icon'] = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)),
                                          'plyer-icon.png')
        elif mode == 'toast':
            self.kwargs['toast'] = True
        print(message)
        notification.notify(**self.kwargs)


class NotificationDemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        notify = NotificationDemo()
        Clock.schedule_interval(notify.update, 5)
        return notify

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NotificationDemoApp().run()
```

And the kv file is OK,list below

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
<NotificationDemo>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Widget:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1, None
        TextInput:
            id: notification_title
            text: 'Put title here'
            size_hint: 1, None
        TextInput:
            id: notification_text
            text: 'Put message here'
            size_hint: 1, None
        TextInput:
            id: ticker_text
            text: 'New notification'
            size_hint: 1, None
    Button:
        text: 'Toast Notification'
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_release: root.do_notify(mode='toast')
    Button:
        text: 'Simple Notification'
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_release: root.do_notify(mode='normal')
    Button:
        text: 'Fancy Notification'
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_release: root.do_notify(mode='fancy')
    Widget:
```

，the buildozer.spec is below:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = SteeringRemind

# (str) Package name
package.name = net.saband.myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.SteeringRemind

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf,wav

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.100.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,pillow,plyer,pyjnius

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/assets/background.jpg

android.presplash_color=#FFFFFF

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/assets/steering.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
#services = NAME:Myservice
#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
#osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
#osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 28

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 17c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path = /home/kivy/Android/android-ndk-r17c

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path = /home/kivy/Android/android-sdk-28

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ant_path = /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
p4a.source_dir = ~/Repos/python-for-android/
# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
#ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
#ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
#ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
#ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 0

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

When I use "buildozer android debug",the apk generated correctly,but with a warning

```
[INFO]:    # APK renamed to net.saband.myapp-0.100.0-debug.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/kivy/Repos/Python3/kivy/examples/demo/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/net.saband.myapp/build/outputs/apk/debug/net.saband.myapp-debug.apk net.saband.myapp-0.100.0-debug.apk
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No compiled python is present to zip, skipping.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
```

And when I install the apk in android phone,it will crash immediately when after presplash show,
if I comment out the lines about jnius like below,the apk can run normally,but the service won't run in background( no prompt pop up in the status bar)

```
if platform == 'android':
    #pass
    from jnius import autoclass
    package_name = 'net.saband.myapp'
    service_name = 'ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY'
    #service = autoclass('{}.Service{}'.format(package_name, service_name))
    #mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
    #service.start(mActivity, '')
```

I don’t know whether I misunderstand the jnius, or the configuration is wrong
Again... any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

After days of testing, I solved the problem

My previous understanding of background operation is indeed problematic,
or my solution is just one of the ways to achieve the goal.

in `main.py`, define the service and start it:

```
from jnius import autoclass
SERVICE_NAME = u'{packagename}.Service{servicename}'.format(
    packagename=u'org.kivy.test',
    servicename=u'Myservice'
)
service = autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
mActivity = autoclass(u'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
argument = ''
service.start(mActivity, argument)
```

in `buildozer.spec`:

```
# (str) Package name
package.name = test

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.kivy

# (list) List of service to declare
services = Myservice:service.py
```

and then, edit the `service.py` as needed. The `main.py` and `service.py` can communicate using [`oscpy`](https://pypi.org/project/oscpy/).

By doing the above, the notification can be popped up after open APP, even the APP is switched to the background.

Comment: in addition : `packagename` in lower-case and `servicename` with the first letter upper-case work for me  : )
ref. : [python-for-android doc](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/)

Answer (score 0):

is this code

```py
from jnius import autoclass
service = autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
mActivity = autoclass(u'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
argument = ''
service.start(mActivity, argument)
```

inside the service.py or main.py

Comment: Inside the `main.py` .

Comment: yes, add it at the `__init__`  method or the `on_start` method

Answer (score 0):

According to https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/ try to change line "services = Myservice:service.py" to "services = Myservice:service.py:sticky:foreground" in buildozer.spec.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33560623)