# Foreground service in Android using kivy

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to execute a Foreground Service in Android using kivy.

I have created a service following different examples in internet, but all of them are killed by Android after some minutes after going to sleep (Doze mode) or even when I change to another application.

I have tried several examples and try different options but no one stays alive after some minutes.

Among others I have tried

https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/

https://github.com/tshirtman/kivy_service_osc

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Background-Service-using-P4A-android.service

[How to keep kivy service running in background in Android (service still run when switch to other App or lock the screen)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218114/how-to-keep-kivy-service-running-in-background-in-android-service-still-run-whe)

It seems that since Android Oreo services spawned by an app will be killed as soon as the app is killed. And if you want to run a service in the background, you need to display an ongoing notification to the user telling them that your app is running in the background. But I do not know how to do that in kivy.

I would apreciate if someone can help me or show an example on how to do it.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: **My solution** at the moment, just in case it can help someone.

Finally I have been able to start the foreground service (so it wasn't killed by Android when phone goes to sleep or when you are using another app) with kivy but I have had to edit one file of buildozer structure.

I have used the example in https://github.com/tshirtman/kivy_service_osc to create the apk I have execute

```
buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat
```

then I have edited `.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/oscservice__armeabi-v7a/templates/Service.tmpl.java` (the service script is in `service.y` file) and I have changed

```
intent.putExtra("serviceStartAsForeground", "{{ foreground|lower }}");
```

by

```
intent.putExtra("serviceStartAsForeground", "true");
```

and then I have executed again

```
buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat
```

I have not found any other way to tell kivy that I want to execute a foreground service. I will appreciate if some knows and shares other better form to do it.

Comment: I'm trying (again) the example in https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Background-Service-using-P4A-android.service but in this line

`service = jnius.autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonService').mService`

it returns None, so the rest of the orders that use `service` raise an error.

`org.kivy.android.PythonService` is a Java file that (among others) assign `None` to `mService` and only when the service is running assigns it a value.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you found the solution? If yes then can you put your files here. I'm also stuck with this